# Why does Node.js commonly use 'var' instead of 'let'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, var, let

Basically every tutorial I’ve watched on Node.js, and even the express generator has all variables declared using `var` instead of `let`? From what I’ve learned in Javascript.info `let` should be the standard unless for very niche cases.

Comment: `const` should be preferred, except in odd cases where a variable needs to be reassigned. `let` isn't so good - in *good* code, it's a warning to readers of the code that it's a variable that's going to be reassigned later (and reassignment should be avoided when not necessary, since it makes the code harder to understand at a glance)

Comment: Instead of assuming there is some sort of standard without really knowing the reason or the effect, it would make more sense to go and research what the different keywords do, and then, each time you declare a variable, use the most appropriate one for the situation

Comment: Not related to Node.js, but sometimes documentation is just old and changing small details like that (which don't have too much influence in the documentation itself) is just a lot of work for little improvement.

Comment: There is no good reason that any body of recently written code would mostly or completely use `var` unless they were trying to maintain compatibility with old JS engines.  Could just be old code.

Comment: The reason is that there a lot of old tutorials out there. Regarding the Express generator, they want to support the Node Version that Express 4 supports. https://github.com/expressjs/generator/issues/167

Answer (score 6):

It is because the Node.JS code is written in ES5 which does not support the use of let and const. If you still wish to write your code in ES6, you need to use something called Babel which will help Node.JS to convert the ES6 code into ES5. But you can definitely use let and const in Node. I hope the answer helps.

Please refer to the below link for an in-depth explanation.
https://dev.to/dhruv/writing-es6-in-your-nodejs-applications-33jk

Comment: In what context does Node only support ES5? When I write code in ES6 (such as with `const`) and then run it with, eg, `node script.js`, it runs just fine.

Comment: `let` is available since version 6 of Node: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility.